# Need help with the substitution method of integrating...

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

Stackers (I tried to be nifty),

I'm currently in a Calculus II course, and we're working through the very basic steps of integrating. I'm really struggling with multiple portions of the substitution method that incorporates the use of *u* and *du*. I'm looking at this problem:
$$\int (x^6-3x^2)^4(x^5-x)dx$$
Now comes my dilemma. I just cannot, for the life of me, understand how the substitution method would work with this equation. I just need someone to break it down for me a bit better than the book is, I'm supposed to find a value of *u* that helps the equation look like:
$$\int u^4du$$
or something, right? If someone could just step through this problem with me, it'll help me greatly with the other 50 questions I have to do with the same concept. Is there any sort of fool-proof analysis that I can do to each problem to know where and how to assign the values of *u* and *du*?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: well, have you an idea for $u$? hint: you are looking for some function $u$ such that the integral looks like (not exactly) $\int (u(x))^4 u'(x) \; \mathrm d x$.

Comment: No, that's what I'm struggling with here. I don't know how to determine what portion of the original equation to designate as *u*. If that makes sense, I need to figure that part out.

Comment: your integral looks like $\int (...)^4(...) \; \mathrm d x$ ... So what would be a candidate for $u$?

Comment: Look for something in the original equation where if you make the substitution $u = f(x)$, you'll also be able to find the derivative $u'=f'(x)$ in the original equation as well.

Comment: I don't know how to write on stackexchange, so I don't know how to use the integral symbol in replies without it going centered and looking weird. Sorry. But, in a sense, my equation should look like:
$$\int(f(x)^4(f'(x))dx$$
or, am I wrong again?

Comment: okay, I make an example $\int (x^3+1)^4 (3x^2) \; \mathrm dx = \int u(x)^4 u(x) \;\mathrm dx = \int u^4 \;\mathrm d u $, where $u(x) = x^3 + 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't like the power of something complicated (in particular, you do *not* want to have to expand the power). So you want the inside of the power to be $u$. (This is a good thing to try in other problems; depending on the setup, it may or may not work.) Then $u'=6x^5-6x$. You pretty much have this already, except for the $6$, but you can bring in constant multiples as you wish, provided you balance them. Specifically, you can write $\int (x^6-3x^2) (x^5-x) dx = \frac{1}{6} \int (x^6-3x^2) (6x^5-6x) dx$. Then with $u=(x^6-3x^2)$, your integral is $\frac{1}{6} \int u^4 du$.

Comment: Thank you for your help on that part, I understand where you're getting the 1/6 and the *u* from now, and it makes a lot more sense. Now, I pretty much just need to pull the anti-derivative of the newly formed equation. Correct? After doing that, I can substitute my original values back in?

Comment: @MLin16 That's right.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, @Ian!